# Compiler error when trying to compile for IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

When i try to compile my app on an IOS 8 Iphone i get this compiler error:

```
fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2Y1THL1FVRI3/UIKit-345QY7DETDSD1.pcm": module file not found'
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2Y1THL1FVRI3'
1 error generated.
```

On IOS 7 it works and if i send my app to itunesConnect and i download it to my IOS 8 it works

Comment: This same question was asked yesterday.  You should search for that question.

Comment: You should find the question and link it as a duplicate. You could also optionally flag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to do.

1. Reset settings and content in simulator.
2. In xcode do Command-Option-Shift-K to do a deep clean of builds folder.
3. After doing the previous steps, if you still have an issue, try deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData this manually.

Comment: Thanks i only had to do a deep clean